# Error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert data into a SQL Server table from C#, which is a `smalldatetime` value. In the table, I can see the data in the format of 2013-10-24 00:00:00.

In my code, I am doing the below to check if the data available in the dataTable is of the right datetime format, before the data is inserted. In the Excel, row containing the string (date value) can be any of the formats, which I have put in the formats array. In the Excel, the data is in form of string.

```
DateTime date;
bool isValidBookedDate = true;

string[] formats = { "yyyyddMM", "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd/mm/yyyy","yyyyddmm" ,                        
                     "dd-MMM-yy", "yyyyMMdd", "dd-mmm-yy", "yyyymmdd" ,
                     "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd" };

foreach (DataRow dtrow in excelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dtrow[5].ToString().Trim(), formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out date)) 
    {
        isValidBookedDate = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isValidBookedDate = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(isValidBookedDate)
{
    // SQL Server insert 
}
```

When the data is passed in the SQL Server `Insert into` statement, I am getting an error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

How to fix this? Thanks

Updated code 1:

```
string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" };
  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(row[5].ToString(), formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
   {
 row[5] = Convert.ToDateTime(date.ToString("{MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss}"));   // this line did not work
}
```

Comment: SQL Server should accept allwasy a string as date in format 'yyyyMMdd' if not time stamp is needed. If full date is needed then use a parameter and write like this : Date.Now.ToUniversalTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")

Comment: When you're doing your conversion your just saying "can this string convert into a datetime object in this format". If your data has some dates with fractional seconds, it will still say that it can as your check isn't about whether it can convert into a smallDateTime but whether it can convert to a c# DateTime object based on a format. Have you got any unusual looking dates?

Comment: Can you show the sql insert code if that is where you are getting an exception?

Comment: Are you attempting to insert the DateTime parameter that DateTime.TryParse() outputs? What does that date variable contain? Also, you can do isValidBookedDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(..) to save an if branch and manual assignment of isValidBookedDate

Comment: As part of you sql insert statement you should also be trying to convert the datetime object to a smallDateTime to ensure it can be converted.

Comment: There’s another potential issue here. If your code accepts both `dd/MM/yyyy` _and_ `MM/dd/yyyy` date formats (as one example), and you’re always specifying `InvariantCulture`, then what are _you_ expecting the value of e.g., `2/4/2020` to be parsed as? `2020-04-02`? Or `2020-02-04`?

Comment: Thanks @JeremyCaney , i have corrected that to use only the MM/dd/yyyy format

Comment: @Wilhelm where should this be used -  Date.Now.ToUniversalTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")

Comment: @Venkat: Weird; I’m not seeing an update to the question (yet?).

Comment: If the date available in the string is in the right format ( wrong formats are: empty string, alphabets, string less than 8 digits ), then I want to insert it to table. I have checked the insert statement and is correct.

Comment: @Wilhelm - code block updated to removed MM/dd/yyyy format. Can you please provide a example code block to handle this

Comment: The insert code is available like this after the datetime.parse - Insert into TableName ([Booked Date],[Eff Date], TestDate) Values ('22/11/2019 00:00:00','01/11/2019 00:00:00','04/04/2020 06:22:01')  .  In the SQL table columns, Booked Date,Eff Date are smalldatetime column, TestDate is varchar

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `Convert.ToDateTime(date.ToString("{MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss}"))`? You already have a DateTime, convert it to s string, and back to a DateTime (the same as the one you had already). And you then try to assign that to what seems to be a string (row[5], which you treated as a string).

Answer (score 1):

Lets have a table called criteria with this fields:
id, name, rank,description,deleted, inserted, registered-user, updated, updated-user,used)

```
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dtrow[5].ToString().Trim(), formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out Mydate)) 
:
:
string insertDate =  (Mydate.Year() + MyDate.Month() + MyDate.Day()
string strSQL = "insert into criteria values (16777214,'new name',1,'new name description',0,'" + insertDate + "',1,'17600101',0,1)"
```

More work but better to user a parameter query. Here I usee OLEDB

```
string[] ParamName = new string[1]; // can be more then one
object[] ParamValue = new object[1];
ParamName[0] = "Inserted" ;
ParamValue[0] = insertDate ; // will insert you date into inserted - simple format yyyyMMdd 
ParamName[1] = "updated" ; 
ParamValue[1] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss"); // will insert current date into updated as complete date
strSQL = "insert into criteria values( 16777213, 'New name',1,'New name description',0,?,1,?,0,1)";

string res = InsertSQL(strSQL, ParamName, ParamValue);


public string InsertSQL(string strSql, string[] ParamName, Object[] ParamValue) 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, sqlConn);
                        for (int i = 0; i < ParamName.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (ParamName[i] != "")
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(ParamName[i], ParamValue[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        return "OK";
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.Print(e.Message);
                        return e.HResult.ToString(); 
                    }
                }
```

And please check the lower case - upper case in my sample - I wrote it here in Stackoverflow and not in visual studio - so there can be a small mistake in my sample.
This will not solve the issue that tryParse can deliver a wrong value because it is doing what the name says: it is trying to parse some string to a valid date. Maybe this should be a different case. So this answer is just to your conversion error in the insertinto code

Comment: Thanks. Should the dates be saved in the format of:  yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss in table. I have the string in the format of 21/12/2019 00:00:00

Comment: Another thing I noticed was , in SQL table - when i ran the sql query , the data gets inserted if date is in format of mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss   . The data I have in excel is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss. I tried below code and I have updated this in first thread

Comment: SQL Server acccept the short date like '20200420' or the long date in he universal format like "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss" or maybe in the local format you are having.

Comment: And you already have converted the Excel value to a valid datetime and assigned it ti a variable. You named it date - in my sample I named it mydate and insertdate for the formated one. In my sample there is one error: I user Mydate in the sql commands but it should by insertDate.